# Awk displays file name twice (?!)

Tags: awk

Greetings.

I have files that contains eleven fields in the file name. Each file has a specific meaning. My job is to list each file name and load the info into a database table for reporting.

My awk code does this (files have VER suffix):

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec ls '{}' ';' -printf %f\\t | awk -F"~" '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$0}' > somefile.tab
```

It works fine except that it does something weird with the file name ($0): it repeats it like so (the 2 last fields from the right):

```
RRR1    PRE DTV_PREP    PREP05  JGM15453.   26  P   H23-600 029416589165    20110216    RRR1~PRE~DTV_PREP~PREP05~JGM15453.~26~P~H23-600~029416589165~20110216~090353.VER    ./RRR1~PRE~DTV_PREP~PREP05~JGMDTV269~33~P~H21-200~029384120357~20110216~091829.VER
```

If I remove "%f" switch from the printf statement, it seems to work but if I leave it alone and remove $0, file name never gets displayed. What am missing here? Any ideas?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` isn't printing it out twice, `find` is due to the `ls` and the `-printf`.  I don't see the reason for the `-exec ls '{}' ';'` anyway.  You should be able to simply remove it like so:

```
find . -name "*.VER" -printf "%f" | awk -F"~" '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"$0}'
```

By the way, you can greatly simplify you code like so:

```
find . -name "*.VER" -printf "%f" | awk -F'~' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("%s\t",$i)}1'
```

*Note* that you were missing the 11th field `$11` in your code. Both my answers will print this out.

Comment: I removed " -printf %f\\t " and replaced $0 with $filename. It works now but display "./" right before the filename. How can remove these two leading characters?

Comment: @Chris see my updated code if you don't want the `./` prefix.  Essentially, leave the `-printf "%f"` and the `$0` but take out the `-exec ls '{}' ';'`

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks so much! I fixed a small glitch in the printf statement though: I changed to "printf %f\\n" otherwise the output is on a single line. Thanks again.